# Getting the "id" value of a control in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox

I have the following code below, that is working for the most part. It returns the value in the textbox control. However, I also need the control's "id" value (the textbox controls name). How can I obtain that?

When I do an "inputs[i]." I only get item and value options.

```
var brSettings = document.getElementById("divSettings");
var inputs = brSettings.getElementsByTagName("input");

var sum = 0
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    sum += inputs[i].value;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to access the id like so:

```
inputs[i].id
```

Comment: dang... thought I was only limited to the options in the intellisense. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simples!

```
inputs[i].id
```

And some extra stuff here to satisfy post length. *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

```
inputs[i].getAttribute("id")
```

should do the trick

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domattribute.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Use the `getAttribute()` method:

```
inputs[i].getAttribute("id");
```

Comment: Although using `getAttribute()` is a more general approach, `inputs[i].id` is the elegant solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `inputs[i].id` to get the id - http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.id

and

`inputs[i].name` to get the name - http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.name

Answer (score 1):

If you were using ASP.Net 4.0 you could set the ClientID=Static and then the name becomes strongly typed.  However, if you are using an older version of the Framework then you can use wildcards. *"inputs" which would give you all the elements that contain "inputs" in the id name.

Comment: Better than wildcards is to get the actual dynamically-generated ID: <%= someControl.ClientID %>